# Using generic methods in protocols Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I believe I have some misunderstanding of how generics work. I have the protocol:

```
protocol CommandProtocol {
    func execute<T>() -> T
    func unExecute<T>() -> T
}
```

And a class that conforms to it:

```
class CalculatorCommand: CommandProtocol {
    ...

    func execute<String>() -> String {
        return calculator.performOperation(operator: `operator`, with: operand) as! String
    }

    func unExecute<Double>() -> Double {
        return calculator.performOperation(operator: undo(operator: `operator`), with: operand) as! Double
    }

    ...
}
```

The calculator.performOperation() method actually returns Double, but here I just try to play with generics so I replace return type from Double to String.

After that, I have a class which invokes these methods:

```
class Sender {

    ...
    // MARK: - Public methods

    func undo() -> Double {
        if current > 0 {
            current -= 1
            let command = commands[current]
            return command.unExecute()
        }
        return 0
    }

    func redo() -> Double? {
        if current < commands.count {
            let command = commands[current]
            current += 1
            let value: Double = command.execute()
            print(type(of: value))
            return command.execute()
        }
        return nil
    }
    ...
}
```

In the undo() method everything works as expected (one thing that I did not understand fully is how Swift really knows whether the unExecute value will return Double or not, or compiler infers it based on the undo() return type?)

But in the redo() method, I am calling the execute() method which returns String, but the method expects Double, so I thought that my program would crash, but not, it works totally fine as if execute() method returns Double. 
Please, could someone explain to me what exactly happens under the cover of this code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you misunderstand generics. First, let's look at this protocol:

```
protocol CommandProtocol {
    func execute<T>() -> T
    func unExecute<T>() -> T
}
```

This says "no matter what type the caller requests, this function will return that type." That's impossible to successfully implement (by "successfully" I mean "correctly returns a value in all cases without crashing"). According this protocol, I'm allowed to write the following code:

```
func run(command: CommandProtocol) -> MyCustomType {
    let result: MyCustomType = command.execute()
    return result
}
```

There's no way to write an `execute` that will actually do that, no matter what `MyCustomType` is.

Your confusion is compounded by a subtle syntax mistake:

```
func execute<String>() -> String {
```

This does not mean "T = String," which is what I think you expect it to mean. It creates a type variable called `String` (that has nothing to do with Swift's String type), and it promises to return it. when you later write `as! String`, that means "if this values isn't compatible with the type requested (not "a string" but whatever was requested by the caller), then crash.

The tool that behaves closer to what you want here is an associated type. You meant to write this:

```
protocol CommandProtocol {
    associatedType T
    func execute() -> T
    func unExecute() -> T
}
```

But this almost certainly won't do what you want. For example, with that, it's impossible to have an array of commands.

Instead what you probably want is a struct:

```
struct Command {
    let execute: () -> Void
    let undo: () -> Void
}
```

You then make Commands by passing closures that do what you want:

```
let command = Command(execute: { self.value += 1 }, 
                      undo: { self.value -= 1 })
```

Alternately, since this is a calculator, you could do it this way:

```
struct Command {
    let execute: (Double) -> Double
    let undo: (Double) -> Double
}

let command = Command(execute: { $0 + 1 }, undo: { $0 - 1 })
```

Then your caller would look like:

```
value = command.execute(value)
value = command.undo(value)
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the Command pattern, and I have done something similar to what you are suggesting: in my CommandProtocol, I just specified the return type (Double), but that decision made my CommandProtocol useless for those cases when I want to implement a command which does not return any values, or return String for instance. I need a return type because this command class is a lawyer between my Sender and Invoker (Calculator), and I need to get a current value of my calculator without directly asking Invoker about it. That is why I tried to do something with generics.

Comment: The (GoF) Command pattern was designed for C++ in a time before it had lambdas. It's not nearly as useful a pattern in environments that have first-class lambdas/closures. A closure is itself a "command object." You need to ask what purpose the Invoker is serving in your design. Is there any other way the Invoker could be implemented? (When there is only one reasonable implementation, then a pattern isn't pulling its weight.)

Answer (score 0):

You think this returns a Swift.Double, but no. This code is no different than using `T` instead of `Double`. Swift does not require the names of generic placeholders to match what you put in a protocol.

```swift
func unExecute<Double>() -> Double {
        return calculator.performOperation(operator: undo(operator: `operator`), with: operand) as! Double
    }
```

You're not actually looking for generic methods. You want this, instead.

```swift
protocol CommandProtocol {
  associatedtype ExecuteValue
  associatedtype UnExecuteValue

  func execute() -> ExecuteValue
  func unExecute() -> UnExecuteValue
}
```